# what happens if the for loop starts and ends at the same value?

Tags: loops

say I have pseudo code that says :

for 1 to 1 do 'something'

would the for loop iterate through once and do 'something' and then fail, or would the loop fail straight away and the 'something' never get executed?

The question is analyse the complexity in relation to n, of this pseudo code:

```
    for i := 1 to 1 do
        for j := n - n^2 to n^2 - 1 do
            k = 0;
```

Comment: its not in a language its pseudo code for an algorithm

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: So..  are you looking at a scenario of `for (int i = 1; i < 1; i++)`? Your pseudo code doesn't exactly paint a clear picture.

Comment: This is the problem i'm having, the question is literally: for i = 1 to 1 do

Comment: From the sound of it, `something` will never be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a pseudo code, `for 1 to 1` should actually execute once, simply going by the notion that intuitively, `for 1 to 2` in pseudo code should execute twice.

If you could share the context where you observed this or the algorithm itself, then perhaps, we could help more. Else this might turn out to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

**Edit:**

As per the updates, in my opinion, the first loop simply exists to see if the reader really understands the notion of complexity. And it should be safe to assume, the first loop executes only once.

Comment: i've added the actual questio